# Unable to read ePub file from mainBundle

Tags: ios

So I'm trying to read a simple epub file that I've download into my project in XCode and therefore should be able to read from my mainBundle, right?

with this code:

```
  NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.feedbooks.com/book/3471.epub"]];

    //Store the Data locally as epub  File if u want pdf change the file extension

    NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

    NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"3471.epub"];
     [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"filePath iss....%@",filePath);
     [detailViewController loadEpub:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath]]];
```

i get bellow error:

```
2015-03-26 15:14:31.301 AePubReader[6742:142694] filePath iss..../Users/pavan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/10E8D95D-A8A3-44B4-BE83-B53701A6B8E6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A07A5926-ED20-4D79-8F37-3D254080C1D8/Documents/3471.epub

2015-03-26 15:14:31.302 AePubReader[6742:142694] -[NSBundle pathForResource:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7facb9629590

2015-03-26 15:14:31.346 AePubReader[6742:142694] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSBundle pathForResource:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7facb9629590'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f400a75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e734bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f407d1d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f35f9dc ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f35f578 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   AePubReader                         0x000000010c6d293c -[AePubReaderAppDelegate
```

please help me,thanks inadvance.

Comment: Are you sure your main bundle contains the `Documents` path? Only when you see a blue folder in your project tree in Xcode will this directory be added, if it is a yellow folder then the file is places in the root of you main bundle. Also use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3471" ofType:@"ePub" inDirectory:@"Documents"]` for getting the path.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are downloading the file in your app and not in Xcode.
This is where  you download the file:

```
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.feedbooks.com/book/3471.epub"]];
```

Which you then try to write to the mainBundle, which is impossible since the mainBundle is read only, thus you want to save to the document directory:

```
NSString *doucmentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
NSString *filePath = [doucmentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"3471.epub"];
NSLog(@"filePath iss....%@",filePath);
[detailViewController loadEpub:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
```

Or using more modern `NSURL` methods with error checking:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *documentURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:&error];

if (documentURL) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to get document directory: %@", error);
    return;
}
NSURL *fileURL = [documentURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"3471.ePub"];

if (![pdfData writeToURL:fileURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error] ) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to write to path %@ with error : %@", fileURL, error);
}
```